# Simulink Embedded Coder: can't find corecrt.h when building dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio, matlab, simulink, nmake

For the record, I solved this problem by resetting my windows system, though the exact reason of this issue remains unknown.

---origninal post---

I've been working on a simulink model for some time, the workflow was:
open the model(a.slx)->change simulation step to "fix step" and target file to "ert_shrlib.tlc"; ->click build(the toolchain is MSVC++ 2019 v16.0 | nmake(64-bit Windows)).

I've done this lots of times during recent months, it always worked. It worked last week and I believe I haven't changed anything that should matter since then(didn't even opened a.slx after last build).

Today I got another model(b.slx), when I try to build it I get this error:

```
C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\crtdefs.h(10):fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file "corecrt.h":No such file or directory

NMAKE: fatal error U1077: ""C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX64\x64\cl.EXE"":return code "0x2"
```

Now I also get this same error when I try to build a.slx again. In addition, I created a simple model(just input port -> output port) and try to build, the error I got is different:

```
"cmd"  is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

NMAKE: fatal error U1077: "cmd": return code "0x1"
stop.
```

"mex -setup c" in matlab shows it is using MSVC++2019(C) as C&C++ compiler. What confused me most is that after last successful build last week, I didn't even use this PC much, definitetly didn't mess with something like environment variables, registry entries, VS2019 & matlab r2022a configurations(and I tried remove and reinstall them already)... Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

====update=====

I use another PC(with VS2019 and matlab r2022a) to build b.slx, it works. I searched for corecrt.h in that PC and found two, in c:\program files(x86)\windows kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt and ...\10.0.19041.0\ucrt, seperately. I removed corecrt.h in 17763 folder, the model can still build; removing the one in 19041 folder yields similar error indicating corecrt.h not found.

However, in my original PC(the one with the issue, there is a corecrt.h in c:\program files(x86)\windows kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt, just matlab seems not searched for it there. Maybe I need to set include dir for simulink? But I didn't find out how. Also again, this worked days ago and I didn't modify much since then.

Also, these two PCs have exactly identical environment variables.